# Batch file in pause continue execution after firefox finish the work and will close

Tags: batch-file, continue, pause

I have a batch file that checking the internet connection, if the connection internet is up, launch firefox with a macro and go on pause.

During this time fiefox works with the macro, after firefox finish the work automatically close.

Now i need to continue the code of the batch opened after firefox finished the works and will be closed but batch file reast in pause.

Exist a solution to continue the batch file opened without manual intervention ?

With firefox I can run another batch file or a software (using some javascript) but i need to continue the execution of batch file opened and I can not find any solution to continue the batch file.

This is the code of my batch file (ping to check connection, sound to alert me, start firefox with macro, pause batch file)

```
PING -n 5 www.wikipedia.org|FIND /I "TTL">NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 start "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Firefox\FirefoxPortable.exe" imacros://run/?m=work.iim
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 PAUSE
```

I do not know how long it takes for firefox to complete the job so I use the pause command.

Comment: `start "" "D:\...\FirefoxPortable.exe" ...` --> `start "" /WAIT "D:\...\FirefoxPortable.exe" ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch is very limited in your use. However, you have two options.

The first being that you can use a `timeout` to let the batch script wait a x amount of time before continuing. The problem with this is that as you said you do not know how long your macro process may take.

```
PING -n 5 www.wikipedia.org|FIND /I "TTL">NUL
IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
    rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
    start "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Firefox\FirefoxPortable.exe" imacros://run/?m=work.iim
    TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK
)
```

The second option will be to (if possible) have the imacros close all instances of the browser when finished. You can have the batch script looking for the process to terminate before continuing. Please keep in mind the reason for `TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK >NUL` is to allow a few seconds for the browser to actually open. Please change both instances of `myapp.exe` to your firefox process name.

```
PING -n 5 www.wikipedia.org|FIND /I "TTL">NUL
IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
    rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
    start "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Firefox\FirefoxPortable.exe" imacros://run/?m=work.iim
    TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK >NUL
    goto Search
)

:Search
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myapp.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myapp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK >NUL
    goto Search
)
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (goto Continue)

:Continue
Echo Macro has finished! Continue code here.
```

Comment: Another solution i think is, the batch file before go in pause can copy the part of code after pause in another batch file with different name, after firefox finish the works before close, force taskkill to close the batch file in pause and start the new batch file with the rest of code after the pause in this mode i split the code of batch in various batch file and every part will be loaded after firefox finish the works. @John Kens I try your second solution and inform if work for me. Any suggestion is appreciated to find a simple solution to my problem, thank to all

Comment: Thanks the solution 1 is not useful because I do not know the time in which firefox will work, the solution 2 works but brings me the 100% cpu it is possible to reduce the workload maybe slowing it down, maybe it's the loop that brings the cpu to 100%. Thanks for help me

Comment: @placidomaio Yeah I will edit my response. We can add a 5 second delay before returning to the loop.

Comment: Response edited. If you want less or more delay change the `5` within the `errorlevel`'s code block to x seconds you want.

Comment: Thanks your solution works like a charms, thanks again.